# module 'bluetooth' has no attribute 'BluetoothSocket' - python3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, bluetooth, connection, raspbian

I'm trying to connect to a bluetooth device with my Raspberry Pi and Python3.

I want to use Bluetooth, but when I run the program, there is an error :

```
Exception : module 'bluetooth' has no attribute 'BluetoothSocket'
```

I made a lot of research but didn't found any working solution.

Here is my code :

```
import bluetooth

serverMACAddress = '98:D3:33:F5:AE:4D'
port = 1
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
```

Comment: Did you name your file bluetooth.py? If so change it to something else, the python interpreter is confusing your script as the Bluetooth module you are trying to import